# Adobe Premiere Pro CC(2015): Cache edited clips

Tags: premiere, adobe

I was wondering if there is any way to cache clips that have been edited in Adobe Premiere Pro CC. I have my main computer and then I have my laptop. I take the laptop out of my house often, and as you can guess, any footage I need to edit is stored on my main computer. Now, I don't want to make low-resolution copies because I don't have very much space on my hard drive (120GB) but caching would be great because when I come home I can just delete the cached files. If there isn't a way I can just make low-res copies, but I thought I would ask first.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

maybe if you used the Adobe Creative Cloud you could upload your footage to it ... if you have an account with them and if you a fast-enough internet connection. otherwise, make lo-res proxies and edit from a USB-3 external drive (since it sounds like you have limited space)